# SQL JOIN two tables based on a pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join 2 tables together, 1 with a word, the other with a pattern

Table 1 would be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYLPp.png)

Table 2 would be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7n9c.png)

I'm trying to get a joined table that looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzJHG.png)

I tried running this but it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 w
JOIN TABLE_2 p on w.Word like( '%' + p.Pattern + '%');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  In MySQL, use `concat()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 w JOIN
     TABLE_2 p 
     ON w.Word like CONCAT( '%', p.Pattern, '%');
```